# Unity DOTween move an instantiated object using DOJump

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dotween

¡Hi! I'm having a problem trying to move an object that I instantiated. What I want is that when the object appears, it "jumps" towards the character to get it using this DOTween command:

```
DOJump(Vector3 endValue, float jumpPower, int numJumps, float duration, bool snapping).
```

I'm looking for an effect similar to this:
https://youtu.be/Mk4R241AZxk?t=786

The current code:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        StartCoroutine(SpawnItem(0.5f, 0.8f));
    }
}

IEnumerator SpawnItem(float delayStart, float delayDisplay)
{
    Transform item = poolItems.GetRandom();
    Instantiate(item, new Vector3(-21.09f, 5.43f, -17.55f), Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 127.29f, 0)));       
    archeologistAnimator.SetBool("Action", true);
    sarcophagusAnimator.SetBool("SarcophagusOpen", true);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(delayDisplay);
    item.transform.DOJump(new Vector3(-5.22f, 2.44f, 40.4f), 2, 1, 5);
    
}
```

"poolItems" is another script file where I call the functions that allows me to list prefab objects and get one at random. The numbers in vector 3 are coordinates of where I want the object to be instantiated in the scene and where I want it to jump to, respectively.

But it doesn't do anything nor does the console give me an error. Any ideas?

Comment: It's been a while since I've used DOTween so I don't know that this will answer your question, but you may want to consider saving the Tween/Sequence that is returned from your call to `DOJump`, at least to make sure it's activated / running as you expect. I think it may be dropping out of scope and thrown away as the coroutine is exited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are changing the transform of your original item, not your newly created instance.

I have not tested this and only changed the needed lines but it should be doing what you want. You could add your directly to the Dotween sequence instead of using the yield return.

```
private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        StartCoroutine(SpawnItem(0.5f, 0.8f));
    }
}

private IEnumerator SpawnItem(float delayStart, float delayDisplay)
{
    Transform item = poolItems.GetRandom();
    var itemInstance = Instantiate(item, new Vector3(-21.09f, 5.43f, -17.55f), Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 127.29f, 0)));       
    archeologistAnimator.SetBool("Action", true);
    sarcophagusAnimator.SetBool("SarcophagusOpen", true);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(delayDisplay);
    itemInstance.transform.DOJump(new Vector3(-5.22f, 2.44f, 40.4f), 2, 1, 5);
    
}
```

Two tips:
Avoid [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) and give more context.
It would be hard for someone else to reproduce since your `poolItems` class is unknown and would need a stand in.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it worked. I also take your suggestion into account, I have already expanded the information in the main post and I will do the same next time.

Comment: Great. Please consider adding the poolItems too class the next time or replace its occurrence in your code with a single transform reference.
This would work the same and allow someone trying to give you an answer to copy your code and run it.